# Can I query map within map in firestore?

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Give me docs where status = 2.
Android/ios/web

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get. And is it for Android, iOS or web?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: That's not a screenshot from the Firebase console.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of Firebase console @anand